# Adding key-value pairs to a dictionary in an ascending order

Tags: python

Say I have a list of words with repeats:

`["Apple", "Orange", "Grape", "Orange", "Watermelon", "Apple", "Grape"]`

I need to put them into a dictionary so that each word has its own key in an ascending order:

`{1 : "Apple", 2 : "Orange", 3 : "Grape", 4: "Watermelon"}`

The order is based on which word appears first. If "Apple" appears first, it will have the key  `1`  and if "Apple" appears in the future, it will be ignored, since "Apple" is already included in 1. If "Orange" appears after "Apple", it will have the key  `2` . Thus, the key-value pairs are added in an ascending order.

I don't have a problem with adding and checking repeats, but I'm struggling with making the keys in an ascending order. Any clues?

Comment: You're not trying to enforce order upon the dictionary, are you? That can't be done; they're inherently unordered. You can have the numeric keys, but don't expect them to print out in order.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. for one, having a sort of index starting at 1 is puzzling at best. then, this performs the same function as mostly a list, since you will access the element by index.

Comment: You could save memory and time just by pruning duplicates from your list, probably. Does it have to be done this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind an import:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> s = ["Apple", "Orange", "Grape", "Orange", "Watermelon", "Apple", "Grape"] 
>>> dict(enumerate(OrderedDict.fromkeys(s), 1))
{1: 'Apple', 2: 'Orange', 3: 'Grape', 4: 'Watermelon'}
```

This works because `OrderedDict.fromkeys` makes an ordered dictionary where the order is insertion order:

```
>>> OrderedDict.fromkeys(s)
OrderedDict([('Apple', None), ('Orange', None), ('Grape', None), ('Watermelon', None)])
```

Comment: so you basically use `OrderedDict` like an ordered set ?

Comment: Yep.  Wish there were one, but until then, that's what I do to fake it.

Answer (score 3):

Just maintain an index and check each fruit against the values of the dictionary.

```
fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Grape", "Orange", "Watermelon", "Apple", "Grape"] 
d = {}
index = 1
for fruit in fruits:
    if fruit not in d.values():
        d[index] = fruit
        index += 1
```

Will give you:

```
>>> d
{1: 'Apple', 2: 'Orange', 3: 'Grape', 4: 'Watermelon'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your `list` into a `set` which eliminates redundant entries but you lose your initial list order:

```
fruit = set(["Apple", "Orange", "Grape", "Orange", "Watermelon", "Apple", "Grape"])
```

The object `fruit` becomes:

```
{'Apple', 'Grape', 'Orange', 'Watermelon'}
```

I find it easier to have the iteration index starting at 1 for cases like these. If you would like to sort your fruits before assigning them to numerical keys in a dictionary you will need to to apply the `sorted()` function to your fruit set for an alphabetical sort (you can also [setup a parameter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions) to sort in other ways using the `sorted()` function).

```
basket = {}
for i, item in enumerate(sorted(fruit), start=1):
    basket[i] = item
print basket
```

Printed result:

```
{1: 'Apple', 2: 'Grape', 3: 'Orange', 4: 'Watermelon'}
```

Comment: Compare your result to the OP's desired result.

Comment: All fixed, just a copy and paste error. I took ascending order in the OPs desired result to mean ascending order by key not by appearance in the original list as illustrated.

Comment: It's not fixed. You're generating the fruit in a different order than the OP desires.

Comment: My first sentence includes that as a caution. It answers half his question now. I thought this method would help since the OP listed no use for this dictionary. You can vote to delete and I'll go along with it.

Comment: I answered the question explicitly where the OP says nothing about preserving the order of the initial list. I took it to mean that the first index in the iterative object would be assigned as a value to the dictionary and would receive the `1` key.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited after the discussion in the comments:**

A pythonic way to check if a key exists in a dictionary:

```
fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Grape', 'Orange', 'Watermelon', 'Apple', 'Grape']
index = 1
basket = {}
for fruit in fruits:
    if fruit not in basket:
        basket[fruit] = index
        index = index + 1
```

Comment: What's wrong with the solution? And it's pythonic to check if a key exixts in a dict with a try-catch, rather than looping.

Comment: now that the indentation is fixed, I guess it is no longer wrong. anyway, what do you mean `rather than looping`? an `if fruit not in basket:` will have the same effect, with shorter code, and without weird looking lines such as `basket[fruit] = basket[fruit]`, which really is only a test to see if the fruit is in the basket (the assignation is useless, btw)

Comment: so I would think that `if fruit not in basket:` is identical to yet clearer than `try: basket[fruit] except KeyError:` (although I agree that in some circumstances, asking forgiveness rather than permission can work)

Comment: Doesn't `in`/`not in` "loop" through the list (check possibly every element in the list)?

Comment: The idea would be that "trying" the O(1) dict access would be better than performing an O(n) `not in` check...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58914/discussion-between-celeritas-and-njzk2).

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Grape", "Orange", "Watermelon", "Apple", "Grape"] 
basket = []
for i in range(len(fruits)):
    if fruit[i] not in basket:
        basket.append(fruit)
```

This doesn't get you a dictionary, but it shouldn't matter, because the elements are accessed the same way: `basket[2] == "Grape"` either way, assuming you correct for arrays being 0-indexed while your desired dict layout is 1-indexed.